# keras input dimensions compatibility

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, conv1d

I have a data of shape (4,34):

```
print(X_train)
array([[[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 1.]],
                  ............
       [[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

and trying to build a keras model as following

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=motif_len, activation='relu', input_shape=(34, 4)))

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=1, data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))  # Output layer for multi-class classification
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

sadly, I'm struggling with incompatibility error, while seemingly I am doing exactly the same procedure as at the [following example](https://saturncloud.io/blog/getting-started-with-keras-cnn-for-1d-data/) (which does work):

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_19" is incompatible with the layer: 
expected shape=(None, 34, 4), found shape=(32, 4, 34)`
```

model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_19"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_19 (Conv1D)          (None, 27, 512)           16896     
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_14 (MaxPoolin  (None, 24, 512)          0         
 g1D)                                                            
                                                                 
 flatten_12 (Flatten)        (None, 12288)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_24 (Dense)            (None, 512)               6291968   
                                                                 
 dense_25 (Dense)            (None, 6)                 3078
```

i was trying to swap the dimensions, which made the code to brake earlier

Comment: What does `X_train.shape` return?

Comment: @maciek97x (400000, 4, 34)

Comment: So your data is not `(34, 4)` but `(4, 34)`

Comment: @maciek97x trying `model.add(Conv1D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=motif_len, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,input_length)))
` fails at the very line, giving: `ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv1d_20. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 4, 34] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.`

Comment: I think you should transpose you data like: `X_train = X_train.transpose(0, 2, 1)`

Comment: @maciek97x it worked, thank you very much! may you write it as an answer and i'll accept it ?

Comment: You are welcome. Sure, added answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the shape of data is `(*, 4, 34)` while the model accepts data of shape `(None, 34, 4)`. You should simply transpose the input like:

```py
X_train = X_train.transpose(0, 2, 1)
```